# How to embed version number & copyright into my DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, dll, copyright-display, version-numbering

I have a VB Express 2008 class library and would like to embed a version number and some copyright/contact info.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select your Project in Solution Explorer. Right click it and select Properties. Select the Application tab. Now click the Assembly information button.

[How to: Specify Assembly Information (Visual Basic, C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts8eta17.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

if the "Assembly Information" button is missing when you: right click the project -> select properties -> Application tab
then check the "Package" tab and scroll to the bottom. youll find assembly version and file version there. i think this is only for .dll projects in visual studio 2017

[image]